# Почему в БД не обновляется запись?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Написал обработчик, который обновляет записи в БД по указанным полям и значениям:

```
class OperationDB():
    def __init__(self, DB):
        self.db = DB

class MyTable_api(OperationDB):
    def __init__(self, db, dbMyTable ):
        super().__init__(DB=db)
        self.dbMyTable = dbMyTable 
    
    def update_table(self, idRows, field_lst, data_list):

        print('Пытаемся обновить таблицу в БД')
        print('idRows=', idRows)

        cash = self.db.session.query(self.dbMyTable).filter_by(id=int(idRows)).first()
        print('cash=', cash)
        if cash is None:
            print('Нет такой строки!')
        for ind, data in enumerate(field_lst):
            print(cash.__dict__[data], '-->', data_list[ind])
            cash.__dict__[data] = data_list[ind]
        self.db.session.commit()
        self.db.session.close()
        print('Обновление таблицы успешно!')
        print('Закрываем сессию!')
```

выдает:

```
Пытаемся обновить таблицу в БД
idRows= 2
cash = ....
.... --> ....
.... --> ....
.... --> ....
Обновление таблицы успешно!
Закрываем сессию!
```

Как видно по выводу, что все успешно отработало("..." - там данные, просто убрал, чтобы глаза не  мозолило) - нигде ничего не встало.

Вопрос только в том, **почему при проверке данных - они не изменились, а остались старые?**

Дополнение:

1. **Библиотека и СУБД:** SQLAlchemy, MySQL
2. Если прописывать вручную, то работает:

```
cash = obj_MyTable_api.db.session.query(obj_MyTable_api.dbMyTable).filter_by(id=idRows).first()
print('Пытаемся обновить таблицу в БД')

print('cash=', cash)
if cash is None:
    print('Нет такой строки!')
else:
    cash.field1 = data_field1 
    cash.field2 = data_field1 
    cash.field3 = data_field1 
    cash.field4 = data_field1 
    cash.field5 = data_field1 
    cash.field6 = data_field1 
    obj_MyTable_api.db.session.commit()
    print('Обновление таблицы успешно!')

obj_MyTable_api.db.session.close()
```

Comment: Для начала, с какой библиотекой базы данных работаете? SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @gil9red, да - SQLAlchemy. А СУБД - MySQL

Comment: Вроде бы должно и так работать. Но попробуйте через `cash.update` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270879/efficiently-updating-database-using-sqlalchemy-orm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменение `__dict__` не влияет на изменение объекта при коммите. Скорее всего, причина в внутренней кухне, мб у объекта есть список измененных полей и они хранятся отдельно и при коммите к ним идет обращение, а если менять объект через внутренний словарь `__dict__`, то свойства не отмечаются как измененные, я так думаю.

Решением будет использовать [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
setattr(cash, data, data_list[ind])
```

Вообще, я бы цикл переписал:

```
for name, value in zip(field_lst, data_list):
    setattr(cash, name, value)
```

---

**PS.**

Для проверки теории с `__dict__` и `setattr` сделал такой тест:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


Base = declarative_base()


class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Foo'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    value = Column(String)
    value2 = Column(String)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.id}, {self.name}, {self.value}, {self.value2}'


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

foo = Foo(
    name="Variant",
    value="<ALL>",
    value2="<ANY>",
)
session.add(foo)
session.commit()

print('Foo:', foo)
print()

cash = session.query(Foo).filter_by(id=int(1)).first()
print(cash)
cash.__dict__['value2'] = '!!!'
print(cash.__dict__)

session.commit()
cash = session.query(Foo).filter_by(id=int(1)).first()
print('Change __dict__:', cash)

print()

setattr(cash, 'value2', '!!!')
print(cash.__dict__)
session.commit()

cash = session.query(Foo).filter_by(id=int(1)).first()
print('Change setattr:', cash)

session.close()
```

Вывод:

```
Foo: 1, Variant, <ALL>, <ANY>

1, Variant, <ALL>, <ANY>
{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x000001F45AA55060>, 'value2': '!!!', 'name': 'Variant', 'id': 1, 'value': '<ALL>'}
Change __dict__: 1, Variant, <ALL>, <ANY>

{'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x000001F45AA55060>, 'value2': '!!!', 'value': '<ALL>', 'id': 1, 'name': 'Variant'}
Change setattr: 1, Variant, <ALL>, !!!
```

Как видно по выводу, значение поля объекта не поменялось при `__dict__`, но поменялось при `setattr` (кст, как и сам `__dict__`)

Comment: Так может достаточно выкинуть этот лишний `__dict__` и писать просто: `cash[data] = data_list[ind]`? А, или это именно атрибут, а не словарь. Ну да, тогда понятно.

Comment: @CrazyElf, будет `TypeError: 'Foo' object does not support item assignment`, проверял с `cash['value2'] = '!!!'`

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вот так должно работать при помощи `update`, но нужно проверять:

```py
        for ind, data in enumerate(field_lst):
            print(cash.__dict__[data], '-->', data_list[ind])
            cash.update({data: data_list[ind]})
```

Comment: В моем тестовом коде `cash.update({'value2': '!!!'})` выдало `AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'update'` :)

Comment: @gil9red Странно, тут вовсю `update` советуют, правда там варианта с `first` нет, но по идее должно работать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270879/efficiently-updating-database-using-sqlalchemy-orm Хотя да, может дело именно в том, что это не набор записей, а одна запись. Не пойму как правильно выскрестись. Наверное, только через ваш ответ )